# Does db_affected_rows() works well with PostgreSQL?

Tags: 6, database

This is a clean installation and I was starting to develop a module.
So I have the following code (and nothing more apart from the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6)):

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {variable}");
return db_affected_rows();
```

I used the `variable` table as an example since it was likely to be populated (and it is, of course!). Well, to my surprise [db_affected_rows()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_affected_rows/6) always returns `0`.
Is there any reason why it doesn't work? Are there any reported bugs that I may have missed?

Setup:

- Drupal 6.22
- PostgreSQL 8.4
- PHP 5.3.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize for Drupal 6:

- `db_affected_rows()` gives you number of rows returned by a select if the database is MySQL but not if it's PostgreSQL.
- In Drupal 6 if you are using PostgreSQL you can run `pg_num_rows()` on the query to get the number of rows.

It is indeed database specific.

<sub>[Reference: [this comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.pgsql.inc/function/db_affected_rows/6#comment-2043) in the Drupal documentation]</sub>

Comment: Well, I don't know why but that's what I was expecting. So much for a database abstraction layer... Thank you.

Comment: There are a several subtle difference like this between the MySQL and PostgreSQL versions.  When you encounter weirdness like this, always read the entry and comments in the API section of the docs.

Comment: @andrematos yeah :) Though they've updated the API for Drupal 7, see (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/db-affected-rows-in-drupal-7-for-db-query) for updates (merges) specifically :)